# Prevent multiple cells from being selected in DataGridView Control

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Can anyone tell me how to prevent multiple cells from being selected in datagridview control?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use the [`MultiSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect.aspx) property

edit: depending on what you want to accomplish, you might have to also use the [`SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode.aspx) property

Answer (score 9):

in the `dataGridView` properties >> **Behavior** section >> set MultiSelect to **false**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to prevent control clicks from multiple columns you can do the following:

```
private int nSelectedColumn = 0;
```

(add a CellClick event on the datagridview and copy in the following code:)

```
    private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift || Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
        {
            if (_nSelectedColumn != 0)
            {
                if (_nSelectedColumn != e.ColumnIndex)
                {
                    dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected = false;
                    if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
                        dataGridView.ClearSelection();
                }

            }
            else
                _nSelectedColumn = e.ColumnIndex;
        }
        else
            _nSelectedColumn = e.ColumnIndex;
    }
```

Also ensure multiselect is enabled and SelectionMode is set to CellSelect.

The effect is that you can control click items in a column and even shift click in the same column.  The cell will deselect when you control click outside of that column and if you shift click outside of the column it will deselect everything.